# Can't render asciiMath through MathJax on a Moodle site

Tags: moodle, mathjax, asciimath

I have configured the Moodle MathJax filter as

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  config: ["Accessible.js", "Safe.js"],
  extensions: ["asciimath2jax.js"],
  TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","color.js","mhchem.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"] },
  errorSettings: { message: ["!"] },
  skipStartupTypeset: true,
  messageStyle: "none",
  asciimath2jax: {
   delimiters: [['`','`']]
  }
});
```

The rendered page successfully processes Tex, but not asciiMath. Looking at the Network tab in Chrome DevTools and it appears asciimath2jax.js is not being requested.